# Auto close Tags doesnt works in neo vim

Tags: vim, neovim

Hi im newbie with neovim and i want to close a Tag
For example

Input `<html` and when i press '>'
i hope this `<html></html>`

how to do this ?

Comment: You need a plug-in to have Vim auto close tags for you, do you have one? Also, check out the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim and NeoVim.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported natively in neovim. You have to add a plugin like https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag

Comment: Thanks, i used it. The configuration for different files. i did add .js file but the recommendation is .jsx. it is a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, neovim doesn't natively do this.  The other answer helps for HTML but for (most) other programming language I use [endwise](https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag):

For HTML tags:  https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag

For other languages:  https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag